# How do display bytearrays from MQTT Response in Python-Flask as stream?

Tags: python, flask, mqtt

From a mqtt callback function i receive about 30 images per second, which looks like:

```
frame = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00 .............'
```

Those byte-frames of an webcam came in (representing an 'image' frame) on a mqtt route.

How can i display these separate bytearray like images as a video-"stream" via Flask on a webpage?